# Adonis.js search queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, adonis.js

I'm trying to find a way to execute a search query using AdonisJs but I cannot find any way to do this with Lucid ORM...

I'm currently using this, but it's clearly not the right way to make a search query:

```
let posts = yield Post.query().with('category').where({
   title: request.input('term')
}).forPage(1, 10).fetch()
```

How can I directly execute postgres SQL queries using adonis.js framework?

```
SELECT id FROM posts WHERE content LIKE '%searchterm%' OR WHERE tags LIKE '%searchterm%' OR WHERE title LIKE '%searchterm%'
```

Comment: What is the point of using all those fancy ORM-s and to seek raw-query execution at the same time?

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution to directly execute SQL queries in Adonis with `Database.schema.raw(execute queries here)`, so:

```
const postQuery = yield Database.schema.raw('SELECT * FROM posts');
const posts = postQuery.rows
console.log(posts);
```

**Edit 1**
To perform a search query with Lucid ORM:

```
const term = request.input('term');
yield Database.select('*').from('posts').where('title', 'LIKE', '%'+term+'%')
console.log(posts);
```

**Edit 2**
Even better raw query:

```
yield Database.select('*').from('posts').whereRaw('title @@ :term OR description @@ :term', {term: '%'+term+'%'})
```

Comment: None of those examples are using Lucid models.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a Model named Post.You can use the following query.

```
const term = request.input('term');
const posts = await Post.query().where('title', 'LIKE', '%'+term+'%').fetch()
console.log(posts);
```

If you want to select all attributes,you don't need to use **select()**
Hope it will help you.

Comment: If assume that 'title' field is number type, it will not work. What recommendations do you have for that?